# This object at .mouseenter() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a simple (I hope it's simple) question. I'm using 10 divs (div1, div2...) and I want to calculate the distance between two of them. I've already clicked one, that takes the class (img.home). I have the function to calculate the distance between two objects `showdistance(div1, div2)`, but How can I use it to calculate showdistance`($('img.home').parent()[0], $(this) )` where (this) is the div, that my cursor is point at at the moment `(   .mouseenter(function() {$(this).text(showdistance)});   )`

Thanks in advance,
If needed, I can make a jsfiddle with the whole code, but as I believe it is a rather easy thing, that I don't know and the code is a large piece it's easier this way.

Best regards.

Comment: please complete code or jsfiddle.

Comment: The jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/r94sN/ 

I want to see the distance, between the object last clicked and the object that the cursor is on (the img.home in the description was in case I didn't have to upload the jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your last clicked element in a variable.
Then compare the position when you enter an element.

You can apply `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom`, if you like.

```
var clicked = null;

$("someSelection").click(function() {
    clicked = $(this);
});

$("someSelection").mouseenter(function() {

    // if-statement to ensure that the event won't fire if you haven't clicked one
    if(clicked !== null) {
        console.log($(this).position().top - clicked.position().top);
        console.log($(this).position().left - clicked.position().left);
    }
});
```

Comment: I used the same idea in the jsfiddle, but for some reason it takes as $(this) some other object, that I don't even know where it is :D

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, figured it out. I need only this, not $(this)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it works. :) / Note, however, that there is a difference between `this` and `$(this)`: `this` returns the HTML on which the event was triggered, `$(this)` does the same, but convents it to a jQuery-object first. While you can apply the position()-method on the jQuery-object, you cannot adopt it on the native `this`. (because it's the jQuery-way) Maybe that makes things more clear.